# exim 4 connection timeout

Tags: networking, exim

I got a pretty strange problem with my Exim mailsserver recently.
Whenever I try to send mail to an emailaddress of a specific hoster (gmx.net) I get a timeout on the MX-Server from this hoster.

> 2012-01-19 11:34:56 1RnpHX-0005oz-0Y mx0.gmx.net [213.165.64.100]
>   Connection timed out
>
> 2012-01-19 11:38:05 1RnpHX-0005oz-0Y mx1.gmx.net [213.165.64.102]
>   Connection timed out
>
> 2012-01-19 11:38:05 1RnpHX-0005oz-0Y == [recipient]@gmx.de R=dnslookup
>   T=remote_smtp defer (110): Connection timed out
>
> 2012-01-19 11:38:05 1RnpHX-0005oz-0Y ** [recipient]@gmx.de: retry
>   timeout exceeded

Mail delivery to [recipient]@googlemail.com works just fine. And if I send an email from googlemail to the GMX-address it works aswell.

So what could be the reason that my server is unable to send emails to GMX?

PS: Just to mention it, I checked the RBL and my IP is not listed. The server I'm sending the mails from has a static IP and valid DNS records.

Comment: Can you telnet from you to either `213.165.64.100` or `213.165.64.102` on port 25? If that works, do you get an SMTP banner?

Comment: I wasn't able to connect on port 25. A further check on my firewall settings revealed that I forget to allow outgoing traffic with destination port 25. So now I'm able to send emails again.

Comment: Same issue, similar solution : my *box was configured to block outgoing SMTP traffic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be your ip(Mail Server's) is blocked in the receiver server. So, check with the receiver side, whether you ip is blocked or not.

Comment: I've asked the provider if my IP might be blocked. Currently waiting for an answer.

Comment: It turned out that my IP wasn't blocked on the receiver site but from my own firewall rules.